# Template matching with multiple source images in OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

The following is the code in Python and OpenCV for image detection using template matching

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('photo.jpg')

template = cv2.imread('template.jpg')

# resize images
image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 
template = cv2.resize(template, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 

# Convert to grayscale
imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find template
result = cv2.matchTemplate(imageGray,templateGray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
top_left = max_loc
h,w = templateGray.shape
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(image,top_left, bottom_right,(0,0,255),4)

# Show result
cv2.imshow("Template", template)
cv2.imshow("Result", image)

cv2.moveWindow("Template", 10, 50);
cv2.moveWindow("Result", 150, 50);

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I want to know how to do the program with multiple source images?

Comment: load images to a container and loop?

Comment: Your code needs better formatting. There is no need to use quote for the content of your question that's not a quote. Also from what you're asking it seems like you want us to write a for loop for you? It is also not clear if you mean source as the template or source as the image compared to the template.

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you mean multiple template images, here is something I tried.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

#empty list to store template images
template_data=[]
#make a list of all template images from a directory
files1= glob.glob('your\\template images\\template*.png')

for myfile in files1:
    image = cv2.imread(myfile,0)
    template_data.append(image)

test_image=cv2.imread('you\\testimage\\testimage.png')
test_image= cv2.cvtColor(test_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#loop for matching
for tmp in template_data:
    (tH, tW) = tmp.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow("Template", tmp)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(test_image, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + tW, top_left[1] + tH)
    cv2.rectangle(test_image,top_left, bottom_right,255, 2)

cv2.imshow('Result',test_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Something to consider is that, while this works very well, it has the overhead of matching the template once again over the entire source image, every time you want to get another match, instead of matching once and looking up and computing only the resulting match.