# Want to speed up template matching in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I am with the code below to detect multiple images on the screen using multiple source images to detect different object on screen.
found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339287/template-matching-with-multiple-source-images-in-opencv-and-python/43341663) with solution but when applied my fps drops down drastically

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
from time import time
import mss


os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

imgs = ['car.png', 'bear.png', 'computer.png', 'log.png', 'utensils.png',
        'bench.png', 'river.png', 'keepdistance.png', 'waste.png', 'player.png']


def findClickPostion(needle_img_path, haystack_img):

    #    haystack_img = cv.imread('/Users/amanrai/Desktop/conquer2020/main.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    needle_img = cv.imread(needle_img_path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)

    threshold = 0.8
    if max_val >= threshold:
        needle_w = needle_img.shape[1]
        needle_h = needle_img.shape[0]
        top_left = max_loc
        bottom_left = (top_left[0] + needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)
        print('Found')
        cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_left, color=(
            0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv.LINE_4)
        cv.imshow('result', haystack_img)
        # cv.waitKey()
    else:
        print('Not Found')


loop_time = time()
with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 450, "left": 0, "width": 1438,
               "height": 450}  # "width": 1500, "height": 860
    while (True):

        screenshot = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        #screenshot = cv.cvtColor(screenshot, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        #cv.imshow('Computer Vision', screenshot)
        for ik in imgs:
            findClickPostion(ik, screenshot)

            print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
            loop_time = time()

        if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            break


print('done')
```

what I want to achieve is  to speed up the process so that it detects multiple objects on screen without losing any fps.
I am using this without GPU.

Comment: The first part of speeding up any code is measuring what is currently using the time. Try to measure your times for acquisition of your image, for the various stages of processing and for display.

Comment: Do it with GPU will speedBoost,
Do it on C++ will speedBoost more

Comment: move the `imread` calls to outside of the function. read those pictures *once*, not in every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here (considering you are not using a GPU to speed up) is working in a single thread of Python instance which is slow.

To speed this up without using a GPU, you will need to parallelize the matching. So you can have multiple templates being matched at the same time. While multi[threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) in Python is tricky, it is possible to speed up things. Having a multi-threaded processor would significantly help. You can have a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to have control over your worker instances.

Beside multi-threading, I can see you are reading all the images from the disk on every loop. This is very costly. Therefore, an optimization here would be to have the template images loaded in memory at the beginning and use them on loop every time.

Besides, you should be measuring where the most time is being used as @MarkSetchell mentioned in the comment.

EDIT: Also consider using GPU for these sorts of works. They improve performance and satisfaction of doing data processing like a breeze.

Comment: reading the images on every iteration should be the *first* thing to mention. that very likely accounts for most of the time spent.

Comment: Use pyramid processing from course to fine resolution. At each step of the higher resolution, just process a roi around the found match from the previous resolution

Answer (score -1):

Instead of template matching use KAZE, SIFT they are faster and more reliable. Template matching is the most basic approach.